# Is there actually a way to complete the escape quest?

Tags: prey

There is a quest to escape Talos-1 using Alex Yu's escape pod. However, once you reach said pod and launch it,

> it basically counts as your death, and the game forces you to reload.

Thus, it seems like in order to finish this quest, you need to lose the game. However, I would like to finish the quest *without* losing, because I don't like quests hanging in my quest log. Is there any way to actually finish this quest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found out during my further playthrough, that this quest plays some role later in game:

> This one of three options player can choose after deciding to destroy station.